# haw to fix when use npm start in react app opens differnce url?

Tags: reactjs, web, npm, github-pages, npm-scripts

I'm use gh-pages for publish project

I had add "homepage": "https://Mohamed0Ahmed.github.io/portfolio", to package.json
[image.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZMdJ.png)

when type npm start expected Url localhost:3000 while show localhost:3000/portfolio
when edit Url to localhost:3000 open page

thank you

Comment: One way I am aware of  is to use react router <Redirect/> component, and to have a redirect to profile when landing at localhost:3000 
<Redirect exact from="/" to="profile" />

Answer (score 0):

Change homepage in package.json to "homepage":"/" will make the application run in your localhost.